# Overpass query Paris metro stations with line numbers?

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api

I understand from the wiki article of [Paris Metro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paris_M%C3%A9tro), that there are 16 lines and 302 stations. Could you help me run an overpass query that can give me the data? i.e I can see which station belongs to which line?

I have seen [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/43766/126816). This [API](http://overpass-api.de/public_transport.html) is built by Overpass DE but do not know whether this is pulling data direct from OSM.

Edit: unless I am not able to spot it, neither of these two does the job in R using `osmdata` package.

```r
paris = opq(bbox = "paris") %>%
  add_osm_feature(key = "station", value = "subway") %>%
  osmdata_sf()

paris2 = opq(bbox = "paris") %>%
  add_osm_feature(key = "type:RATP", value = "metro") %>%
  osmdata_sf()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here you get the stations: https://overpass-turbo.eu/s/IC4

An easy way to get into overpass is to use the 'assistant' in https://overpass-turbo.eu/

There you put in `station = subway` and the engine makes the query you need.

You can export the results in different formats.

EDIT: from comment, to get "tracks" or lines, https://overpass-turbo.eu/s/IHA

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Two things, maybe you could improve the answer. I think that gives me 431 stations, which is not the ~302 I am after and also I cannot see the "line" number of the metro lines. Cheers.

Comment: The number of the metrolines are not added to the railway-stations.  With this query you return both: https://overpass-turbo.eu/s/IHA.  If you want to add this information to  the railwaystation (= node) you have to make spatial join in for example QGIS

Comment: If I am allowed, I will replace your query in the answer with the one in the above comment. I just downloaded that as `geojson` and I get 312 rows. Plotting line 4 is close to what I see [here](http://urbanrail.net/eu/fr/paris/paris-map-centre.png) so I think I should mark it as "ticked".

Comment: Processed in R
![image](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/408568/57377933-8b277800-719b-11e9-86f7-e3f609268089.png)